# Change start time extensible calendar (extjs)

Tags: extjs, calendar, extensible

I trying an extjs component (extensible calendar)

http://ext.ensible.com/

I want change the start time in day view become 4.30, but the data doesn't show after 23:00.

This is make me crazy T.T

Please, any suggestion please...

Answer (score 1):

set the `viewStartHour  : Integer` config of the day view.

[Read docs here](http://ext.ensible.com/deploy/dev/docs/)

Answer (score 0):

Set viewStartHour and viewEndHour on fly !!

```
var cal = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#app-calendar')[0];
var activeView = cal.getActiveView();

activeView.body.viewStartHour = 6; //you most use an variable!!
activeView.body.viewEndHour = 12;

activeView.body.tpl.viewStartHour = 6;
activeView.body.tpl.viewEndHour = 12;
activeView.body.tpl.constructor();

activeView.body.refresh(false);
```

Enjoy!!!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The question is not on-topic for Stack Overflow as defined in the [help]. Please don't answer such questions; instead, you should flag them for attention and they will be closed or migrated appropriately.